# How to remove the focus of a QGraphicsTextItem from a main QWidget

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicstextitem

I have a number of `QGraphicsTextItem` and `QGraphicsItem` painted inside a `QGraphicsView`. This `QGraphicsView` has been added to the main `Qwidget`.

I have written the "`FocusOutEvent`" for this `QGraphicsTextItem` and the focus is getting removed only when the "`MousePressEvent`" is called within the `QGraphicsView`.

Now my concern here is, How to remove the focus of this `QGraphicsTextItem` when the `MousePressEvent` is called Outside the `QGraphicsView`?

In my *MainWindow.cpp*, I wrote a `mousePressEvent` function :

```
void EyGuiMainWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
  QWidget *w = QApplication::focusWidget();
  if(w)
     w->clearFocus();
}
```

But this is not clearing the `QGraphicsTextItem`.

Expecting a positive response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A QGraphicsTextItem is not a widget, but a [QGraphicsItem](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html). Graphics items are added to a QGraphicsScene and viewed by one or more [QGraphicsView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html) widgets.

The code presented is only calling clear focus on the currently focussed widget, but since the QGraphicsTextItem is not a widget, it won't be cleared.

In order to clear the focus on the QGraphicsTextItem, call its [clearFocus](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#clearFocus) function. If you don't have a pointer to the item, you can get a list of all the items in the scene with the [items()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html#items) function and iterate through them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I used the Items() to get the list of scene items and iterated over them to clear it. It worked fine.